# cannot play or copy corrupted video

Tags: file-system, video, file-transfer, files

I have a Samsung galaxy S4. I have changed the settings so that the pictures and video taken from the phone camera are saved in a folder on the external memory card.

Usually this works quite well.

I took a quite long video recently (>1 min) resulting in a file of 119MB.

**The issue:** The file seem corrupted. If I play it with VLC on my phone, it works for the first few seconds, then VLC crashes.
I have tried to copy the file to my PC using [Airdroid](http://www.airdroid.com/), but the download fails at some point after 11.3MB (each time exactly at the same point). hence I suspect it is an issue with a bad sector on the memory card (Although I am not a specialist and open to other possibilities)

I have done a few searched on Internet but not found any solution so far.
I tried for instance [this tutorial](http://janit.iki.fi/repair-corrupted-mp4-video/), but this assumes that I can copy the file which I can't.

It is a great video so I really would like to recover it. Help!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following steps to see if your issue is getting resolved:

1. Install Web PC Suite from Play Store
2. Open the IP address shown on your phone or use scan QR code
3. Then try to download your file on your computer

This software is really good, fast and works very well.

Second method:

1. You can try using an OTG cable (on-the-go cable for S4)
2. Connect your pen drive to your phone using the OTG cable and then see if you are able to copy the file to your pen drive.

Since you have mentioned AirDroid in your question, I believe you want to do it wirelessly, so you can try "Web PC Suite".

There are other ways too, but you can try the first method to see if your problem gets resolved.

Comment: If the file is corrupt, using a different program to copy it won't change the result.

Comment: I had similar problem last week and I thought the file was corrupted but after copying it to my computer it worked just fine. Just a suggestion to the user to make it work. Using different program helped many times in my experience.

Comment: @Sam is the software you are refering to "PS (pc suite wifi explorer)" by editor "SPIDREN INC." ?

Comment: No it is not the right one.. software is called "web pc suite v1.0.3" by Geeksoft.. I am giving you the link from where you can download this software from play store  or app brain https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.geeksoft.wps  or http://www.appbrain.com/app/web-pc-suite/com.geeksoft.webdroid please try. I use this software regularly and it works very well.